# How can I create an Instance of a class that is normally generated with a generic method?

Tags: c#, activator

I am implementing a Library where i have to make some casts to get an instance of a class, from the documentation from the .dll we can find a working code example

```
   public void Example()
    {
        DeviceItem deviceItem = ...;
        GsdDeviceItem gsdDeviceItem =((IEngineeringServiceProvider)deviceItem).GetService<GsdDeviceItem>();             

        var attributeNames = new[] { "TypeName", "Author", "Comment" };

        foreach (var attributeName in attributeNames)
        {
            object attributeValue =
                ((IEngineeringObject)gsdDeviceItem).GetAttribute(attributeName);
        }
    }
```

i want to implement a method to look something like this:

```
public object GetAttributeFromService(DeviceItem item, Type serviceType, string attributeName)
    {

        object a = Activator.CreateInstance(((IEngineeringServiceProvider)item).GetService<serviceType>());

        return ((IEngineeringObject)a).GetAttribute(attributeName);
        
    }
```

and i get the error CS0118 'serviceType' is a variable but is used like a type, it would be very nice if someone can help me

Comment: Could you use a generic method? Something like `public object GetAttributeFromService<T>(DeviceItem item, string attributeName)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If IEngineeringServiceProvider inherits from IServiceProvider, use:

```
var service = Activator.CreateInstance(((IEngineeringServiceProvider)item).GetService(serviceType));
```

That's all